# Drag column width in Cgridview yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

How to drag the table column width in CGridview using jQuery in Yii.

I tried colResizable() jQuery function but its not working properly.Is there any method to do this.

Please refer the below link. What i need exactly in that.

```
$(function(){
      $("table").colResizable();
});
```

[Link](http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/#usage)http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/#usage

image 1 -Before adding colResizable function

[image: Before adding colResizable function]

[image: After adding colResizable function]

image 2-After adding colResizable function

The column not draging.

Comment: Please explain "its not working properly". What HTML does you CGridview  produce. In what way does that generated code differ from the structure colResizable presents in his example fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/euka4rm3/)?

We can't help you, without more information.

Comment: I want Cgridview column re sizable. How to make that?

Comment: Again: Please provide source code of your problem so that we may be able to pin down the problem. I just searched for a CGridview fiddle and added colResizable libraries. It was working as expected. That's why I assume it has something to do with your specific code.